# エクセルから読み込んだ数値データが形が変わって出力される

Tags: python, pandas

エクセルから読み込んだ数値データをvscode上で表示すると、小数点まで表示される。
例えば2という値だと、2.0と表示される。こちらを小数点を抜きにしたいと考えています。0001が1.0と表示されるのを0001のまま出力したい。

・エクセルデータの値をそのまま出力したい
・vscode上の出力[.0]を表示されないようにしたい。
どちらもExcelの設定の問題であれば、そこもご教授いただければ助かります。

```
import padas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("check.xlsx",sheet_name="Sheet1")
for df_ch in df["key"]:
    if str((df_ch)).isdigit():
        print("数字")
    else:
        print("数字ではない")
```

上：エクセルデータ
下：vscode出力画面
[image: Exceldata]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: で、しつもんはなんでしょうか

Answer (score 0):

Pandas のオプションで書式設定として `.0f` を指定してやればよさそうです。

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.0f}'.format
```

**参考:**
[有効数字（有効桁数）: display.float_format | pandasの表示設定変更](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-option-display/)

Answer (score 0):

0001が1.0と表示されるのは、取り込み時に`float`型であると自動判別されるのが原因です。
0001のまま前ゼロを落とさずに出力したいならば、取り込み時に`dtype=str`を指定して文字列として取り込みます。

なお上記の内容については[前回のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/90862)の複数回答で言及されています。
この回答よりも詳細な解説が多いので、ぜひそちらも読み直していただくことをお勧めします。

**サンプルコード**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", dtype=str)
print(df)
```